# How to resize div to make room for a dynamically added submenu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

What I want to do:
let A(menu), B(3d scene) and C(sub menu) be div elements that are laid out horizontally and take the whole space vertically. 'A' has a width but B takes all remaining space.

When A is clicked, C would be added next to A.

I want to shrink B to make space for C without overflowing.

What I tried:
The following code works fine but i am not sure if this is a good way to implement what i want.
Keep in mind that A is supposed to be a menu and c a sub menu and B a 3D scene. Here is a good example of what i am trying to do: https://webshed.royssheds.com.au/

```js
let uiWrapper=document.getElementById('ui_div');
let mainWrapper=document.getElementById('mwrapper');
function makeRoomForC(){
    let c=document.createElement('div');
    c.className='sub_menu';
    c.innerHTML="C";
    uiWrapper.appendChild(c);

}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.container{
    display:flex;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:green solid;
}
#ui_div{
    display:flex;
    border:brown solid;
}
#menu_button{

    background:yellow;
    border:red solid;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
}
#scene_div{
    border:blue solid;
    flex:1 1 auto;
    object-fit: contain;
}
.sub_menu{
    background:yellow;
    border:red solid;
    width: 250px;
    height:100%;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <title>flexbox exp</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="main_container" class="container">
            <div id="ui_div">
                <div id="menu_button" onclick="makeRoomForC()">A</div>
            
            </div>
            <div id="scene_div">B</div>         
        </div>
        <script src="code.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```